# Perform template function based on type provided at runtime

Tags: c++, templates

Occasionally, I'd like to perform some type-specific action that is based on a string I receive at runtime.  It would be nice to have a function that can add a type to a function template based on the string.  For instance, the following example that *is supposed to* ask the user for a type, and print some information about that type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename F, typename ... ArgsT>
auto call_with_type(std::string type, F f, ArgsT... a) {
    if (type == "int") {
        return f<int>(a...);
    } else if (type == "double") {
        return f<double>(a...);
    } else if (type == "float") {
        return f<float>(a...);
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::string get_type_name() {
    return typeid(T).name();
}

template <typename T>
bool is_integral() {
    return std::is_integral<T>::value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Enter a data type: ";
    std::string type;
    std::cin >> type;

    std::cout << "Type " << call_with_type(type, get_type_name);
    if (call_with_type(type, is_integral)) {
        std::cout << " is integral.";
    } else {
        std::cout << " is not integral.";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `call_with_type` function is the important part. It should execute the function `f` with template argument deduced from the string `type`.  I know this program will not compile at all as is, but is there any way to implement `call_with_type`, or am I grossly misunderstanding how templates can be used?

Comment: Templates resolution and deduction is completely and solely left to compile time, there's no way.

Comment: Using a `std::variant` or `std::any` and the visitor pattern can do this.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well yes, but that still is resolved at compile time.

Comment: What do you want `call_with_type` to return if the string is not one of the types in your list?

Comment: I suppose a default constructed object would make the most sense.  So `call_with_type("undefined", get_type_name)` would return an empty string.  Would this be more feasible if `call_with_type` always returned `void`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag dispatching might help:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
auto call_with_type(std::string type, F f, Ts... args) {
    if (type == "int") {
        return f(Tag<int>{}, args...);
    } else if (type == "double") {
        return f(Tag<double>{}, args...);
    } else if (type == "float") {
        return f(Tag<float>{}, args...);
    }
}
```

Change your call to:

```
template <typename T>
std::string get_type_name(Tag<T>) {
    return typeid(T).name();
}

std::cout << "Type " << call_with_type(type, [](auto tag){ return get_type_name(tag);});
```